# Uploading file to Hbase HDInsight

Tags: c#, .net, azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I have an azure subscription, so I have created a hadoop cluster under hdinsight.
I have to upload a file to this hadoop. I am not getting how to continue

```
var myCluster = Hadoop.Connect(
            new Uri("https://samplecluster.azurehdinsight.net/"),
            "admin", "admin", "sample",
            "storageacc.blob.core.windows.net",
            "key",
            "cluster", true);
```

By using the above code, I am able to connect to the hadoop cluster , but I am not getting how to upload files later.

Edit:
 There are a few examples which makes of powershell/cli commands to upoad the files ,but is there any sample applications which is written in .net?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Hadoop cluster or a HBase cluster in HDInsight?  HDInsight clusters use Azure Blob storage for storing data.

If it is a Hadoop cluster, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/

If it is a HBase cluster, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hbase-tutorial-get-started/